# Convert String[] to ORA_MINING_VARCHAR2_NT from java stored procedure

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, type-conversion

Can i convert String[] from stored procedure to "ORA_MINING_VARCHAR2_NT" as return value? VARRAY is not an option (i have variable number of elements)

I always get an error :

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected a return value that is an instance of a user defined Java class convertible to an Oracle type got an object that could not be converted
```

in this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED Parser AS
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;

public class Parser {

    public static oracle.sql.ARRAY parseToArray(String str, String delim) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
        ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("ORA_MINING_VARCHAR2_NT", conn);
        ARRAY result = new ARRAY(descriptor, conn, str.split(delim));
        return result;
    }
}
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
PARSETOARRAY (str IN VARCHAR2, delim IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN ORA_MINING_VARCHAR2_NT AS
LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Parser.parseToArray (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) return oracle.sql.ARRAY';
/
DECLARE
v_array ORA_MINING_VARCHAR2_NT;
BEGIN
  FOR testing IN (SELECT record FROM interfacelog) LOOP
    v_array := PARSETOARRAY(testing.record, '|'); 
    -- do smth
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Thank you!

ps sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was solved it. Its work fine with some other classes:

```
create or replace type stringArray is table of varchar2(4000);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED Parser AS
import java.sql.Connection;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Array;

public class Parser {

    public static Array parseToArray(String str, String delim) throws SQLException {
        OracleDriver ora = new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver();
        Connection conn = ora.defaultConnection();
        OracleConnection oraConn = (OracleConnection)conn;
        Array arr = oraConn.createARRAY("STRINGARRAY", str.split(delim));
        return arr;
    }
}
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
PARSETOARRAY (str IN VARCHAR2, delim IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN STRINGARRAY AS
LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Parser.parseToArray (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) return java.sql.Array';
/
DECLARE
v_array STRINGARRAY;
BEGIN
  FOR testing IN (SELECT record FROM interfacelog) LOOP
    v_array := PARSETOARRAY(testing.record, '|'); 
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Always specify schema name for your type passed to `createDescriptor` as parameter.

Comment: @Cool-T - Try `oracle.sql.ARRAY result = new ARRAY(...);`

Comment: Doesnt work. Already tried. Perhaps java cannot convert to this type, because it is a TABLE type =/